# PHP: can connect in terminal access denied in browser (Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a PHP script that connects to a database, selects rows from a table:

**db.php**:

```
    function connect()  {
        try {
            $this->connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

            if ($this->connection->connect_error) {
                die("\nConnection failed: " . $this->connection->connect_error);
            } else {
                print "\nConnected successfully\n";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e)  {
            echo 'Exception: ' . $e -> getMessage();
            die("\nConnection failed: " . $this->connection->connect_error);
        }
    }
```

It works without fail when I run it in terminal - connects and retrieves all the data from the table.

However when I copy the file to a `/opt/lampp/htdocs/myapp` and open it, I get the error:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myapp/db.php on line 15
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 
Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myapp/db.php on line 61
```

I don't know how to fix it. I tried to add `192.168.1.1` to `/etc/hosts` file. Now it looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   parsecer
192.168.1.1     parsecer

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I tried commenting out the `bind-address` line in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` :

```
...
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
#mysqlx-bind-address    = 127.0.0.1
...
```

However I still get that error...

**EDIT**: I managed to replicate the access denied error inside Terminal (IDE) by using `localhost:3306` instead of just `localhost` as a host name...

**EDIT**: I tried running like this:

```
 $this->connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "correctpassword", "stuff", 3306);
```

1. In Terminal (IDE) it WORKS
2. In browser - access denied error

I also have this in the `mysqld.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

**EDIT**:

```
select user, host from mysql.user
```

gives this:

[image]

**EDIT**:

I created a new user in MySQL, gave it all privileges, the code works
with the new user in Terminal doesn't in browser.

**EDIT**:

I turned off MySQL in XAMPP panel, but MySQL still works in terminal, so I think there are two different MySQLs on my PC.

Now the code works in terminal but in browser gives

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/stuff/db.php on line 16
Connection failed: No such file or directory
Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /opt/lampp/htdocs/stuff/db.php on line 67
```

I also added

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

to `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER**:

A user @Shadow guessed correctly that I had two versions of Postgres running simultaneously. One I installed manually and the other was installed with a XAMPP package.

I removed the whole XAMPP package, manually installed Apache server (which was part of the XAMPP as well), and then, having only one Postgres and one Apache manually (using terminal) run both and the code worked!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248361/discussion-on-question-by-parsecer-php-can-connect-in-terminal-access-denied-in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user @Shadow guessed correctly that I had two versions of Postgres running simultaneously. One I installed manually and the other was installed with a XAMPP package.

I removed the whole XAMPP package, manually installed Apache server (which was part of the XAMPP as well), and then, having only one Postgres and one Apache manually (using terminal) run both and the code worked!