# mysqli on php denied access from webserver but not on command line

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm seeing an issue where `$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser,'', $db);` is giving me `Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php(6): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'user', '', 'foo') #1 {main} thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php on line 6` although running this file in the command line works just fine. I found a similar thread here [PHP: can connect in terminal access denied in browser (Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73858869/php-can-connect-in-terminal-access-denied-in-browser-warning-mysqli-constr) , but I'm on mariadb installed with homebrew on macos and the thread seemed to have been resolved by having uninstalled XAMMP, which I don't have installed.

I also tried to pass `127.0.0.1` as my host instead of `localhost`.

the linked duplicate post has nothing to do with my issue in this post as that post is reporting issues with opening the mysql system client to access a database, whereas I'm reporting issues with not being able to access the database through mysqli on a webserver.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with mysql versions, hosting providers or software collections. It simply means that provided credentials are wrong. Just like when you login to Stack Overflow and it says that password is incorrect, you don't change the browser or PC. You just provide the correct login and password. As simple as that.

Comment: @YourCommonSense the credentials I passed would be identical from the webserver as from the command line. I'm not sure why I see success in one but not the other.

Comment: given both web-server and command line are on the same host, it means that  identical credentials should work. So we can conclude that they are not indentical.

Comment: what exact command you are using from cli?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm running `php index.php` with my script looking like this:
`<?php 
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$db = 'foo';

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser,'', $db);
$result = $mysqli->query("select * from users");
foreach($result as $r){
  echo $r['ip']."\n";
}
?>`

Comment: what exact command you are using from **cli**? CLI means **command line interface** you mentioned earlier

Comment: When CLI works and php do not probably is due to mysql configuration. On CLI even if you specify the host as localhost or 127.0.0.1 it goes by socket, but in php it goes by host. Check mysql configuration if it allows netwrok connection (skip-networking should be commented) and bind address (bind-address  = 127.0.0.1)

Comment: @RobertoBraga that's not true. Both can connect both ways

Comment: @YourCommonSense from mysql manual: On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs: the client connects using a Unix socket file. The --socket option or the MYSQL_UNIX_PORT environment variable may be used to specify the socket name.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html mysql programs means mysql mysqldump etc etc, php has its own internal implementation that use any hostname, included localhost, as hostname

Comment: @RobertoBraga that's your [wrong] conjecture. PHP doesn't have anything own, it uses the same API from mysql. That follows everything you written about Unix

Comment: @YourCommonSense from PHP manual: MySQL Native Driver **is a replacement for the MySQL Client Library (libmysqlclient)**. MySQL Native Driver is part of the official PHP sources as of PHP 5.3.0. 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd.php and from PDO_mysql page: **Mysqlnd is the default library**. For details about choosing a library, see Choosing a MySQL library. 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: @YourCommonSense MysqlND has been developed for better integration in PHP. One of the issue using mysql client library use double amount of memory: php  execute the query, libmysql retrieve the data, php copy all the data from libmysql. Therefore, during the script execution, you had the recordset stored twice once in php and one in libmysql without considering the time and cpu work for the copy. MysqlND solve this issue plus other. From mysql site https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

Comment: @RobertoBraga sorry, I am lost here. Is it related to the problem in the Opening Post?

Comment: @RobertoBraga by the way, where I can read about that double memory issue? I had no idea it existed.

Comment: doing this fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035939/write-privileges-localhost-mac-osx

Comment: @YourCommonSense >Is it related to the problem in the Opening Post? Yes read my first post >by the way, where I can read about that double memory issue https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/post/mysql-native-driver-for-php-mysqlnd reduced memory footprint -- keeps every row only once in memory, where as with libmysql you have it twice in memory

Comment: @RobertoBraga your initial post mention the non-existent difference between cli and cgi environments. None of your later comments support this claim. Either way, it seems the issue has been resolved already. Hardly surprising, the alleged "solution" is also irrelevant to the problem.